# Docker OSX Unable to Access Container via IP Address

Tags: docker, containers, virtualbox

I'm having some strange issues with Docker on Mac. When I set up a container I am unable to access it via the containers IP address.

I installed Docker, along with Docker Quickstart Terminal. I've created a basic `Dockerfile` to test:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.04
MAINTAINER Me <me@gmail.com>

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y nginx
RUN echo "Testing" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]

EXPOSE 80
```

I build with:

```
docker build -t james/nginx .
```

And then run with:

```
docker run -d james/nginx
```

I didn't use `-p 80:8080` in this instance because at the moment I'm just trying to figure out why I can't access via the containers IP. I can't even ping it.

The container has been giving the title `admiring_snyder` (Got to love Docker's naming scheme). So I run `docker inspect admiring_snyder` to get the machines IP address:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f",
        "Created": "2016-03-14T18:22:24.179971826Z",
        "Path": "nginx",
        "Args": [
            "-g",
            "daemon off;"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 6837,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2016-03-14T18:22:24.245675122Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:921ad9259637823006e092e9ee6441a410fd1c60f2d599ace0ad8a3200d170c7",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f/2d9ac50726ea5d20905c50f2453aa20cc46eebbcac21966d7cdb29a469ad3c7f-json.log",
        "Name": "/admiring_snyder",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "aufs",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {},
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                0,
                0
            ],
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "KernelMemory": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": -1,
            "OomKillDisable": false,
            "PidsLimit": 0,
            "Ulimits": null
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Name": "aufs",
            "Data": null
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "2d9ac50726ea",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "80/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "nginx",
                "-g",
                "daemon off;"
            ],
            "Image": "james/nginx",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": null,
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {},
            "StopSignal": "SIGTERM"
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "aab80a46210e9ad79b53c60294912ed57a77968ac3178d0cf32ad40f2207e236",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "Ports": {
                "80/tcp": null
            },
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/aab80a46210e",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "f5610deaced494b6a6c692a6e79bbe838f04574bb95f86b3c2b688477f724087",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "af5e68119aa41c3fbae80be8760b9382773533ae2c971253970740083ac9e202",
                    "EndpointID": "f5610deaced494b6a6c692a6e79bbe838f04574bb95f86b3c2b688477f724087",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.4",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:04"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Which shows the IP address:

```
"IPAddress": "172.17.0.4"
```

I am unable to connect to this IP address. I have a feeling it's something to do with docker being ran on a VM (obviously there's no alternative to this). But, I've no idea how to solve it.

The VM has the IP `192.168.99.100`. I got this from `docker-machine ip default`.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You can launch the image with a port mapping;

```
docker run -d -p 8080:80 james/nginx
```

This will map port 8080 on the *docker vm* to port 80 in the docker container as can be seen in `docker ps` under PORTS;

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS
6c8b6d1a7d3d        james/nginx         "nginx -g 'daemon off"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8080->80/tcp                          focused_spence
```

In your case, http://192.168.99.100:8080 will show your test page.

Comment: `192.168.99.100` is the IP of the VM. If I set up two services in seperate containers that need to be accessible over port `80` this wouldn't be possible. Is this a limitation or can this be solved?

Comment: @BugHunterUK As far as I know (although Docker changes fast) it's not available out of the box with the docker command, however there's nothing preventing you from logging onto the docker vm and creating your own network bridge so the machines are exposed directly. I'd call that an [advanced topic though](https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/).

Comment: @BugHunterUK The containers can (by default) communicate with each other without any extra mapping though, it's only external ports (accessible from the host Mac) that need to be mapped like that.